# post name, email and role in django backend, react frontend error 400

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, api

i want to the admin to post name, email and role of a user using frontend, and its stored in backend of django, please note that i dont want the admin to store the password, the user will later on add it. Following code is giving **error 400** when i enter name, email and role

djangocode:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'username', 'password', 'role']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data('password')
        username = validated_data('username')

        user = UserAccount(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            role=validated_data['role'],
            name=validated_data['name']
        )
        
        if username is not None:
            username=validated_data['username'],
          
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            
        user.save()
        return user
```

react code:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name : name,
      email : email,
      role: role
    };

   console.log("data is "+data);
   axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/', data)
    .then(response => console.log("got it"+response.data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log('name:', name);
    console.log('email:', email);
    console.log('role:', role);
```

Comment: Is your `UserAccount` model is Django's default `User` model? If that's the case then you need to customize `User` model and make your `password` field `blank=True` or `null=True`. You can make your `password` field optional in your `UserAccount` model too.

Comment: Other than that, paste the error you are facing. That would be helpful for other.

Comment: yes ive done blank=True and null=True before, im getting error 400

Comment: As per [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields:~:text=If%20you%27re%20using%20Model%20Serializer%20default%20value%20will%20be%20False%20if%20you%20have%20specified%20blank%3DTrue%20or%20default%20or%20null%3DTrue%20at%20your%20field%20in%20your%20Model) if you are using `blank=True` in model then `ModelSerializer` will mark that field as `required=False` during deserializing. So make sure you migrated your changes to DB properly.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ["email", "name", "username", "password", "role"]

    def validate_password(self, value):
        user = self.context["request"].user

        if user.role == "admin" and value is not None:  # mean admin is setting password
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Only user can set password")
        
        if user.role == "user" and value is None:  # Ask user to set password
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User must set password")

        return value

    # Your create method and other code
```

Here we are conditionally making our field required based on user role.